# How to display fields according to a value in an other

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I've got one head scratcher of a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I'm doing a VF page in witch I want to display fields according to a number inserted by user in an other fields. For example, if the user insert 2 in the field "A" it will display two fields in the same page.

```
// Page
<apex:page standardController="Assure__c" extensions="insEnfant"
standardStylesheets="true">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Ajouter un assuré"
    subtitle="{!$User.FirstName}" help="/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help"></apex:sectionHeader>
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Nouveau assuré" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Enregistrer"></apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="   Annuler   "></apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="liste1" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Civilite__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Nom__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Prenom__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Nom_de_jeune_fille__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Date_de_naissance__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Lieu_de_naissance__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Pays_de_naissance__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Nationalit__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Situation_Familiale__c}"></apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Numero_de_securit_sociale__c}"></apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="liste2" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Telephone_bureau__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Telephone_personnel__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Portable__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Adresse_e_mail__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Adresse__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Code_postal__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Ville__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Pays__c}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Pays__c}"></apex:inputField>


                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Nombre d'enfants" />
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Nombre_enfants__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock"
                                status="statut1" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:actionStatus startText="Application..." id="statut1" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel
                        value="{!$ObjectType.Assure__c.fields.Etudes_superieures__c.label}" />
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Etudes_superieures__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock"
                                status="statut2" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:actionStatus startText="Application..." id="statut2" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Service militaire" />
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Service_militaire__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock"
                                status="statut3" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:actionStatus startText="Application..." id="statut3" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection
            title="Entrez le niveau d'études supérieures atteint" columns="1"
            rendered="{!(Assure__c.Etudes_superieures__c)}">

            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Type_etudes__c}"></apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Diplome_obtenu__c}"></apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Nombre_annees__c}"></apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection
            title="Entrez les informations concernant le service militaire"
            columns="1" rendered="{!(Assure__c.Service_militaire__c)}">

            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Type_de_service__c}"></apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Date_de_debut__c}"></apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Assure__c.Date_de_fin__c}"></apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Liste des enfants" columns="1"
            rendered="{!IF(Assure__c.Nombre_enfants__c > 0, true, false)}">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accts}" var="a" id="table">
                <apex:facet name="footer">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Ajouter" action="{!addRow}"
                        rerender="table,error" />
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:column headerValue="Nom">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Prénom">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Prenom__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Né le">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Date_de_naissance__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Lieu de naissance">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Lieu_de_naissance__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Situation">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Situation__c }" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

// Controller

public class insEnfant{

public List<Enfants__c> accts {get; set;}

public insererEnfant(){
    accts = new List<Enfants__c>();
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());
}

public void addrow(){
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());
}

public PageReference save(){
    insert accts;
    PageReference home = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
    home.setRedirect(true);
    return home;
}
}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would involve using rerender combined with a table structure.  You need to establish a collection (labelled "dataCollection" below) within the controller.  This collection drives what is displayed and what will be captured.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
  <apex:inputField value="{!controllerObject.NumRows__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refresh}" rerender="dynamicTablePanel"/>
  </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>

<apex:outputPanel id="dynamicTablePanel">
  <apex:pageBlockTable id="dynamicTable" value="{!dataCollection}" var="dataRow"
    columns="2">

    <apex:column headerValue="Column A" title="">
      <apex:inputField value="{!dataRow.ColumnA__c}" />
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="Column B" title="">
      <apex:inputField value="{!dataRow.ColumnB__c}" />
    </apex:column>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

This will require additional work in the controller.  You must handle the refresh action, to add or remove collection records as needed.  You must also handle the Save button; you must save the controller record and also cycle through the collection items and save them somewhere.  I suggest using a child object for the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, I did this, but I still have problems, I can't resolve them, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Html dinamically, I think you should use Javascript or a Javascript framework like JQuery, but I cannot get what you intend to do.

Please, be more specific. What type of fileds you want to add? Are those input fields? or will be outputFields? Can you know beforehand the information to display?

Maybe you can use an apex component and rerender it doing a javascript request.

Comment: Thanks, I want to display input fields, so I don(t know beforehand the informations to display. I want to display a table with input fields and the rows depands on a number in a fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at based on input in one field, you allow/disallow display of other fields?

You could have all the fields you want to display and control the visbility of the that field using the rendered tag.

```
  <apex:outputField value="{!item.field1__c}" >
                         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displayOtherCols}" rerender="mainBlock2"/>  
  </apex:outputField>

<apex:column headerValue="Name" >
                <apex:outputField value="{!item.field2__c}"  rendered="{!(item.field1__c == 'option1')}" />
<apex:outputField value="{!item.field3__c}"  rendered="{!(item.field1__c == 'option2')}" />
            </apex:column>
```

You can use actionsupport to call a method which would process and set which fields should be rendered by . In this example i am directly checking the value of field, you can either do this or set the value of a boolean variable in displayothercols method and use that variable to render the fields. make sure you rerender the block .

in this example if the field1 has "option1" then another field field2 is displayed and if field1 is "option2" then field3 is displayed

Hope this helps..

good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to display a table in witch the number of rows (evry row have input fields) depands on a number in an onther fields. For example, if the user enter 2 in the field, a table will be displayed with two rows (input fields). I hope that you know how I can proceed.